# luajittex ignores fonts luatex finds

Tags: luatex, context

With `LuajitTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019)` and `ConTeXt  ver: 2019.02.26 20:04 MKIV beta  fmt: 2019.3.1` I can run the following MWE:

```
\setupbodyfont[postscript,sans,12pt]
\starttext
Test
\stoptext
```

Adding `% engine=luajittex` at the top breaks everything:

```
$ context font.tex 
mtx-context     | redirect texlua -> luajittex: luajittex --luaonly "/home/stenner/.local/bin/mtxrun" --script context font.tex --redirected
mtx-context     | run 1: luajittex --fmt="$TEXDIR/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luajittex/cont-en" --jobname="font" --lua="$TEXDIR/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luajittex/cont-en.lui" --c:currentrun=1 --c:engine="luajittex" --c:fulljobname="./font.tex" --c:input="./font.tex" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 --c:redirected --c:texmfbinpath="$TEXDIR/bin/x86_64-linux" "cont-yes.mkiv"

This is LuajitTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 system commands enabled.
open source     > level 1, order 1, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-yes.mkiv'
system          > 
system          > ConTeXt  ver: 2019.02.26 20:04 MKIV beta  fmt: 2019.3.1  int: english/english
system          > 
system          > 'cont-new.mkiv' loaded
open source     > level 2, order 2, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv'
system          > beware: some patches loaded from cont-new.mkiv
close source    > level 2, order 2, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-new.mkiv'
system          > files > jobname 'font', input './font', result 'font'
fonts           > latin modern fonts are not preloaded
languages       > language 'en' is active
open source     > level 2, order 3, name '/tmp/font.tex'
open source     > level 3, order 4, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-postscript.mkiv'
open source     > level 4, order 5, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv'
close source    > level 4, order 5, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-texgyre.mkiv'
close source    > level 3, order 5, name '$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-postscript.mkiv'
fonts           > defining > font with asked name 'texgyreheros-regular' is not found using lookup 'file'
fonts           > defining > unknown font 'texgyreheros-regular', loading aborted
[snip]

fonts           > !! No bodyfont has been defined and no defaults have been
fonts           > !! loaded (maybe due to a missing \starttext).
```

In theory, ConTeXt is able to find the font:

```
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list texgyreheros

identifier            familyname     fontname              filename                   subfont   instances

texgyreherosregular   texgyreheros   texgyreherosregular   texgyreheros-regular.otf
```

Comment: For a context question the tag luaotfload is wrong.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with latest beta.  I'm also curious where you obtained this version of ConTeXt.  My local version still reports `This is LuajitTeX, Version 1.09.2 (TeX Live 2019/dev)`.

Comment: Could you try executing the following: `context --make; contextjit --make; mtxrun --generate; mtxrunjit --generate`.  If that doesn't fix it, try additionally `mtxrun --script fonts --reload; mtxrunjit --script fonts --reload`.

Comment: @HenriMenke `tlmgr info context` reports it as context revision 50165. After rebuilding everything with `mtxrunjit` and using `contextjit` instead of the `%% engine = luajittex` comment it produced the same output as plain `context`

Comment: @tstenner So the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes, with `contextjit` / `mtxrunjit` the formats were created correctly (in the case of contextjit even automatically), so I'll switch to that instead of the comment

Comment: Using `contextjit font.tex` is also slightly faster than using `context font.tex` and having `% engine = luajittex` in the first line, because in the latter case, ConTeXt has to start up, parse the magic comment, and then restart with a different engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when ConTeXt can't find files which you are sure are there, or complains about undefined control sequences which you are sure are defined, or chokes on mismatched formats, try rebuilding the ConTeXt formats and caches:

```
# Remake the formats
context --make
contextjit --make
# Regenerate the file database
mtxrun --generate
mtxrunjit --generate
```

If you are loading fonts by fontname, rather than by filename (e.g. `TeX Gyre Heros` rather than `texgyreheros-regular.otf`) you should also reload the font database:

```
mtxrun --script fonts --reload
mtxrunjit --script fonts --reload
```

Comment: Actually reloading the file and font database with both `mtxrun` and `mtxrunjit` might be unnecessary.  It's probably sufficient to just use one of them, but I haven't tried.